# Swagger Ui(SwashBuckle for Core) is not throwing UI level Error Message for Mandatory Headers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am currently developing a WebApi with Swagger Ui. i am facing one weird issue. I have some Header fields those i have setup as Mandatory (*required) fields when a user try to call an API.

If a user misses to pass any header it suppose to show warning as given in Image-1.(In image-1 the red marked field is Query param) which is working fine but not working for Header.
[image]

For Headers i am getting the Issue as shown in the Image-2. Error suppose to come on the UI but its coming in the browser console window.
[image]

Code in IOperationFilter as follows

```
public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            if (operation.Parameters == null)
                operation.Parameters = new List<OpenApiParameter>();

            operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter
            {
                Name = "X-Transaction-Id",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Required = true,
                AllowEmptyValue=false,
                Description="Transaction Id to track the issue"
            });
       }
```

NB:- I have used `IOperationFilter` to set the required headers.Using `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore(5.6.3)`. Any help on this will be really great!!

Comment: Your header parameters seem to be missing the `type` (data type). Please post your `IOperationFilter` code.

Comment: Added in the Question. For all Headers i have added in same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must specify the `Schema` (data type) for header parameters, such as:

```cs
            operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter
            {
                Name = "X-Transaction-Id",
                ...

                Schema = new OpenApiSchema   // <-----------------
                {
                    Type = "string"
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks Helen, it worked, i will accept this as answer. If any other parameter that we can set for better User experience?

Comment: Make sure the parameter description is descriptive enough. If needed, you can also add schema attributes to narrow down possible values. For strings, you can specify min/max length, [format](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.3.md#dataTypes) (such as `"uuid"` ), and/or regex pattern. For numbers you can provide the min/max values.