# Swagger Ui(SwashBuckle for Core 6.2.3) is not throwing UI level Error Message for Mandatory Headers

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm having the same issue. these are my lines of codes. It was working fine until I update the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore to 6.3.1 from 6.2.3.

ref to the previous question: [Swagger Ui(SwashBuckle for Core) is not throwing UI level Error Message for Mandatory Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65405197/swagger-uiswashbuckle-for-core-is-not-throwing-ui-level-error-message-for-mand)

```
operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter()
{
    Name = headerName,
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Description = attribute.Description,
    Required = true,
    Schema = new OpenApiSchema
    {
        Type = "String",
        Default = new OpenApiString(attribute.DefaultValue)
    }
});
```

Comment: 1) What's the header `Name`? Security headers such as `Authorization` are supposed to be defined as [security schemes](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#add-security-definitions-and-requirements) instead of header parameters. 2) If you remove the `Default` value from the schema, does it resolve the issue? Required parameters are not supposed to have default values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had resolved the issue by reverting my library to previous one, until Microsoft releases next version with the fix, the issue was with this version of the lib